# How to properly bind text box value back to model in a observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a model  that has an observable array, I can display the data in a text box, but I can't figure out how to bind it back to the original array.

Here is the working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/GGXdf/) I have.

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: frameworks'>
    <li>
        <button class='btn' value='pick me'             
            data-bind='text: name, click: $parent.selectFramework'>            
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type='text' data-bind='value: selectedFramework().name' />
<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedFramework, null, 4)'>
</pre>



var Framework = {
    name: ''
};

var App = new function () {
        var self = this;
        self.frameworks = ko.observableArray();
        self.selectFramework = function (item) {
            self.selectedFramework(item);
        };
        self.selectedFramework = ko.observable(Framework);
    };

App.frameworks([{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]);

ko.applyBindings(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to make the 'name' properties on each framework observable. I have updated your [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GGXdf/1/)

```
App.frameworks([{
    name: ko.observable('foo')
}, {
    name: ko.observable('bar')
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is only stored in your selectedFramework observable, so you would be able to access it via App.selectedFramework(). The observable doesn't take any variable and make it observable, it will store whatever value you pass it internally. If you want to update the external Framework variable, you would do that in your selectFramework function.

```
self.selectFramework = function (item) {
        self.selectedFramework(item);
        Framework = item;
    };
```